# Find and delete inactive tfs branches

Tags: sql-server, tfs

Is there any built-in way to find and delete (`tf destroy`) branches of TFS project that were inactive (I mean there were no check in operations) for a long time, let's say 1 month. Either tfs tools or maybe sql script that can do it would be ok.

Comment: Answer is positive, but it is a bit of effort setting up a working example.

Comment: Yes you can do it using SSRS against the Warehouse database with some API, our BI developer set it up so I don't have the details other than the API query. However, I would advise caution using tf destroy unless you really don't care about the history of the changes before merging into Main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, whole thing wasn't hard, posting code here, might help someone:

```
private static string _tfLocation; //location of tf.exe
private static string _tfProject;  //our team project

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _tfLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("tfLocation");
    _tfProject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("tfProject");
    var keepAliveBranches = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("keepAliveBranches").Split(',').ToList(); //branches that we keep anyway
    var latestDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3); //we delete all branches that are older than 3 months

    var folders = ExecuteCommand(string.Format("dir /folders \"{0}\"", _tfProject));
    var branches = folders.Split('\r', '\n').ToList();

    branches = branches.Where(b => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(b) && b.StartsWith("$")).Select(b => b.Remove(0, 1)).Skip(1).ToList();
    branches.ForEach(b => b = b.Remove(0, 1));

    foreach (var branch in branches)
    {
        if (keepAliveBranches.Contains(branch))
            continue;

        //get latest changeset
        var lastChangeset = ExecuteCommand(string.Format("history \"{0}/{1}\" /recursive /stopafter:1 /format:brief /sort:descending /noprompt", _tfProject, branch));
        var changesetDate = DateTime.Parse(Regex.Match(lastChangeset, @"\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}").Value); //get it's date 
        if (changesetDate < latestDate)                          
            //destroy
            ExecuteCommand(string.Format("destroy \"{0}/{1}\" /recursive /stopafter:1 /startcleanup /noprompt /silent", _tfProject, branch));            
    }
}

//execute console command and get results
private static string ExecuteCommand(string command)
{
    var process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(_tfLocation)
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Arguments = command
        }, 
    };
    process.Start();
    var result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it but you need to write a small program that uses the TFS API to check each branch and delete the unused ones.

You can use a simple C# console app and I can tell you from experience that the TFS public API is quite intuitive and easy to use. You can get started with it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx).

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youhana/archive/2010/10/04/displaying-all-branch-hierarchies-in-tfs-2010.aspx)'s how to display all the branches.

Answer (score 1):

Unused branches contain element modification history, rather than deleting them writelock the branch and leave it. The space that is recovered is not significant.